# How To Play A Local Sound File

Tags: java

I want to make a program that plays sounds and displays png images onto the JFrame. I am trying to put the png and sound files (.wav) into the package that the class that's displaying it is in. I can't seem to get it working though. I've looked up many methods on how to do it, it every time they all pop up NullPointer errors. Or that it couldn't find the file, even though the file path specified was exactly where it was when I went into File Explorer. So if anyone can help me find a way to play music and display the picture (getting the png file and making it an ImageIcon), that would be great.

Comment: What have you tried? Can we see your code?

Comment: Take a look at this: ftp://sccn.ucsd.edu/pub/virtualmedia/AePlayWave.java. This has worked for me in the past to play a .wav file.

Comment: Well, I have tried multiple methods, but the base code for it was: https://i.imgur.com/OOnfhVj.png The only thing I've really been changing was the path on the script, AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream("Path");

Comment: I actually don’t use Audio Input Streams when I play my audio.

Comment: @PrashantSaraswat When I tried your script, it gave an error for NullPointer

Comment: @Potato If you want to be helped you will need to be more descriptive. There are a hundred lines in the file I sent you. A nullpointer could be anywhere. You have to say what you tried. For example, something like the following works in my case: new AePlayWave("C:\\classical.wav").start();

Comment: If the resources reside within your package/jar, then you need to use `Class#getResource` which returns a `URL` which you can then pass to the things like `AudioInputStream` (or use `Class#getResourceAsStream` if your need a `InputStream`)

Comment: For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24481887/playing-wav-song-in-java/24482048#24482048)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I have tried that, it came up with an NullPointer exception. I used the script I said earlier, but replaced the (new File("foo/file.wav") I used Main.class.getResourceAsStream("file.wav")

Comment: Then it would seem that the file does not reside in the same package as the `Main` class. Unzip the Jar and make sure the files are been included

Answer (score 0):

[image: Player]
[image: File structure]

## Here is java code

### Play Button action Performed

```
private void play_btnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
                                    
     SetImage();
     PlaySound();
}
```

### Play audio

```
void PlaySound() {

    try (InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("sam.wav")) {
        InputStream bufferedInS = new BufferedInputStream(in);
        try (AudioInputStream audioInS = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(bufferedInS)) {
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(audioInS);
            clip.start();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

### set image

```
void SetImage() {

    audio_icon.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/player/player.png")));
}
```